# My first react app: a calculator using codepen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, calculator

I have for the time beeing 2 major problems.

The first one I don't understand why but I can't use any `<button>`. I had to switch it to `<input type="button"/>`.

The second one is that my function  addDecimal is not working as intended.

```
addDecimal(){
  this.setState( prevState => {
    if (prevState.input.includes(".")) { 
      return prevState;
    } else { 
      console.log(prevState);
      return {
        input: prevState.input.concat("."),
        //result: prevState.result,
        //operation: prevState.operation,
      };
    }     
  });
}
```

When I fire the function, the check fails and still add a dot.

Here is the codepen link https://codepen.io/Dali213/pen/QWbwbOb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `<button>` element is of `type="submit"`. So in this case you could use `<button type="button">` to achieve the same effect as `<input type="button">`. `<button>` elements are easier to apply CSS to.

Also buttons with `type="submit"` are useful when POSTing to a `<form>` while buttons with `type="button"` are useful for non-form posts.

---

As for your second question, I'm not seeing the issue your described.

When I click the button that calls the `addDecimal` function, the first time it runs it correctly adds the `.` and logs out `console.log(prevState);` and then any time after that function is called this code is successfully run: `if (prevState.input.includes(".")) {return prevState}`

You could simplify this function by exiting early if the `state.input` contains a decimal already:

```
addDecimal(){
  if (this.state.input.includes(".")) {
    return;
  }

  this.setState( prevState => {
    return {
      input: prevState.input.concat("."),
    }; 
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking some time to answer, it is really helpful. 
It is really strange, every time I press the "." it still adds a dot in the screen input in my browser, even with your function.
secondly is it safe to add the state.input outside of the function? since React can do asynchronous re render won't it lead to some mistakes?

Comment: `this.state.input` is safe if you wanted to check if any dot exists currently in state. It'll get you the same result as if you put it in the `setState` callback like you have it (since you want to check if in the existing state a dot is present). As far as your issue, I only see 1 dot ever appear when pressing the dot button. Can you give a step by step reproduction of what buttons you are clicking and the result you are seeing?

Comment: It might have been a codepen bug. When I closed the browser and opened it again this morning it was gone, every thing works perfectly now thank you